# How can I create a compiler error if a variable is NOT of type never?

Tags: typescript, typescript-never

Let's say I have a list of conditionals and I want to handle every possible value of `type`. If I added a new `type` in the future and I forget to handle it, I want an error - at least a run-time error, but ideally a compiler error so I catch my mistake before I deploy.

How can I assert that a variable is of type `never`?

```
type Job = { type: 'add'; payload: any } | { type: 'send'; payload: any }

const handleJob = (job: Job) => {
  const add = (job: Job) => {
    console.log(job)
  }
  const send = (job: Job) => {
    console.log(job)
  }

  if (job.type === 'add') {
    add(job)
  } else if (job.type === 'send') {
    send(job)
  } else {
    // `job` is actually type `never` here,
    // this error won't ever be thrown unless additional strings are added to the `Job.type` schema.
    throw new Error(`Unhandled job.type "${(job as Job).type}".`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make your code a [mre] that compiles when I paste it as-is into an IDE and I'll show you how to do it.  Otherwise I'm fighting with an IDE trying to figure out what `add` and `send` and `job` should be (especially `job`, because "// `job` is actually type `never` here,"  doesn't seem to be accurate in my IDE)

Comment: (see prev comment) You could do as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAaRPm) but I made some assumptions about your code that I don't know are warranted. Please [edit] to clear this up and let me know if my suggestion meets your needs or not, so I know how to proceed here.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, you're right, I've expanded on the pseudocode and now it shows the error. And thanks for your comment - that does the trick! If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce a [`never`-returning function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions) which only accepts an argument of [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), meaning that the compiler will only be happy if it doesn't actually expect the function to get called. This function is usually called `assertNever()`. Here's one way to write it:

```
function assertNever(x: never, msg?: string): never {
  throw new Error(msg ?? "unexpected value " + String(x));
}
```

If it *does* get called then you'll get a runtime error. Now the following compiles as expected:

```
if (job.type === 'add') {
  add(job)
} else if (job.type === 'send') {
  send(job)
} else {
  assertNever(job, // <-- okay    
    `Unhandled job.type "${(job as Job).type}".`
  );
}
```

But if we add a new job type:

```
type Job =
  { type: 'add'; payload: any } |
  { type: 'send'; payload: any } | 
  { type: 'explode' }; // add this
```

now it *fails*, also as expected:

```
if (job.type === 'add') {
  add(job)
} else if (job.type === 'send') {
  send(job)
} else {
  assertNever(job, // error!   
    // -----> ~~~
    // Argument of type '{ type: "explode"; }' is 
    // not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    `Unhandled job.type "${(job as Job).type}".`
  );
}
```

The compiler error warns you that you haven't handled the new type, which should hopefully prompt you to add another [`if`/`else` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYGd0FMBOMByWAbrgBQAeAXMhMbgDTIC26A5gPzXow5wSsBKarRI5kAb2DJkMABY4EAdxpZlAURwKcpFq2Tt2yAESQs5AA5ZYWACbIiqADZgsx5AGpkAZR59WFAQEAbmAAX2AImABPS2QAKQQAI2QAXikJGRisagByVBsbHKDkc1QoxwR86lQIKORQ5AAfdPFMy1zsCELi0vLKm2ra+vTGjOj25ByzcwqbLBz64oB6JbQCmVk4dAioJG5kWRqbRywE5JTkUgArJOozgVSAPgl03Yh9-LsL69v4pIeUs9JNJpG90AgTgA6Cr+G6JATpcKgvYwZCdL6XOF3f5PF4g5BgiFYaEIWH-RERaRwECYpKQ8auFJMyafHIPYEgz4-eGI5BYRzYZDU2mJelZVLMnLotl4kHo7kI6QNfmCjnSDDYPCEUTcxgrPmaBA4ACEIPS+P1AFprdbngA-B3mkH6gCCOFYYCYWAgqIQNIZk1aDOoRmmsywRmKoQWW2QTuk+ogCFRGrgrAgqESJxkCBKqBwqC9MFwyD9bVcOREuBykPjyAABgBVCCHLonOxwsWxIwAEnE3LQ6D+8K7WFCRkh9adwQpoSAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `Error` class to create an error type whose constructor expects an argument of type `never`:

```
class NeverError extends Error {
  constructor(check: never) {
    super(`NeverError received unexpected value ${check}, type should have been never.`)
    this.name = 'NeverError'
  }
}
```

Then you throw the error if the code is ever reached, and if `job` isn't `never` it'll also raise a compiler error:

```
  if (job.type === 'add') {
    add(job)
  } else if (job.type === 'send') {
    send(job)
  } else {
    throw new NeverError(job)
  }
```